# How do I find equal values in multiple arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

In my program I could wind up with 2 or more arrays. Looking something like this:

```
int[] aa = new int[5] {23, 63, 99, 26, 13};
int[] bb = new int[3] {99, 13, 23};
int[] cc = new int[7] {5, 23, 72, 88, 99, 100, 65};
```

Each number in each array is unique but there could be matching numbers in separate arrays.

Is there an easy way th find all matching numbers that match through all arrays?

Comment: Can you add some code you have tried?

Comment: What does "a value in array1 is equals to a value in array2" mean? Do you want to see if there's a value that exists in all arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ. If you just need to know, if there are duplicates:

```
array1.Any(value1 => array2.Any(value2 => value2.Equals(value3)) &&array3.Any(....))
```

If you need the duplicated values itself, replace the first Any behind array 1 with a Where.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to find the intersection of multiple sequences? The following code snippet shows how to do this using LINQ's [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
// using System.Linq;
var array1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var array2 = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var array3 = new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
var array4 = new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

var result = array1.Intersect(array2).Intersect(array3).Intersect(array4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

The result would be: `4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

Comment: If I have say 3 arrays array1 = new[] {23, 41, 66, 3, 9};  array2 = new[] {8, 9, 23}; array3 = new[] {9, 40, 12, 18, 77, 30, 23, 85};  I would want to find all of the duplicated numbers in the different arrays. In this example I would find 9 and 23. I hope this helps better.